# How can we measure light quality, quantity and duration in the field?

Tags: visible-light, measurements

I am interested in measuring the light availability for coffee plants under a range of different adaptation practices (shade, cover crops etc). We want to ensure that the measurement can be automated (i.e. a sensor that can be left for a number of months) and covers the three relevant aspects of light for plant growth. That would be quality (the wavelength), quantity (intensity/concentration) and duration.

Having searched through the ecological scientific literature there is a wide range of approaches with many people just using Lux. I am therefore interested in learning from people who have researched light in the lab and have a better technical understanding of the different attributes of light how they can be measured, inferred or extrapolated.